# How to transform features order to make their distribution normal?

Tags: machine-learning, python

After sns.pairplot(df) command, I got this picture:[image]

The question is what transformation to use in order to make the distributions normal?

Comment: Try some of these:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735025/how-to-normalize-a-numpy-array-to-within-a-certain-range.    It depends on what you really want when you say "normal".

Comment: There’s little requirement for variables to be normal in regression models. Two common misconceptions are that the $Y$ in an OLS model should have abnormal distribution (correct assumption is that the error term, estimated by the residuals, is normal, and even that is one of the less important assumptions of OLS) and that the features ($X$-variables) in OLS should have normal distributions (correct assumption is that features have no distribution requirements and might even be discrete or designed to be uniform).

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at a pairplot isn't enough to suggest changes, in my opinion. Moreover, what are you trying to test? What is your null hypothesis, what is the alternative hypothesis? What kind of data is it, how neat was your collection process? Are there any co-variables?

With the info provided, all I can suggest is to perform parametric and non-parametric tests. May try Box-Cox transformation!